# How to solve this system of ODE's?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I'm not sure how to proceed to solve this system of ODE's;

$$ \begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_1 \\\dot{x}_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \cos t & -\sin t\\ \sin t & \cos t   \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't that the rotation matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a linear system of the form
$$
x'=A(t)x,
$$
where $x\in\mathbb R^2$, $A(t)\in C(\mathbb R;\mathbb R^{2\times 2})$, and most important
$$
A(s)A(t)=A(t)A(s). \tag{1}
$$
Satisfaction of $(1)$ implies that the solution of 
$$
x'=A(t)x,\,\,\,x(0)=\xi_0,
$$
is equal to 
$$
x(t)=\exp \Big(\int_{0}^t A(s)\,ds\Big)\,\xi_0.
$$
In our case
$$
A(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}\cos t & -\sin t\\ \sin t&\cos t\end{matrix}\right),
$$
then
$$
\int_0^tA(s)\,ds=\left(\begin{matrix}\sin t & \cos t-1\\ 1-\cos t&\sin t\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Next we use use the fact that
$$
\exp\left(\begin{matrix}a & -b\\ b&a\end{matrix}\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}\mathrm{e}^a\cos b & -\mathrm{e}^a\sin b\\ 
\mathrm{e}^a\sin b&\mathrm{e}^a\cos b\end{matrix}\right),
$$
and finally we obtain that
$$
x(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}\mathrm{e}^{\sin t}\cos(1-\cos t) & 
-\mathrm{e}^{\sin t}\sin(1-\cos t)\\ 
\mathrm{e}^{\sin t}\sin(1-\cos t)&\mathrm{e}^{\sin t}\cos(1-\cos t)\end{matrix}\right)\,\xi_0.
$$